# Windows Glitching

Tags: window, bug-reporting

When I first open a app, the window will glitch almost all the time, Firefox, Thunderbird, Tor, Gnome Tweaks, Variety etc. Some parts starts blinking, it fixes itself when I press the Super Key, which opens the Activities screen. Does someone know how to fix it?

---

**Configs:**

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x64. My DE is Gnome 3.36.9

CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 5500U | GPU: Integrated AMD Renoir

[Here's Variety glitching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCUAG.png)

Comment: Hello. What is the version of Ubuntu? What is the exact question? What DE are you using?

Comment: @David I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x64. My DE is Gnome 3.36.9, and I want to know what is causing it, so I can fix it.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: Indeed, include info on your graphics card. You are working on a laptop and on battery?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long.
@ArchismanPanigrahi I don't, I'm using this CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 5500u with radeon graphics, and integrated graphics is AMD® Renoir.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, I'm using a Laptop, it's a Aspire A515-45, but it happens either way, with or without the power cable plugged.

Comment: There is no information on the graphics card in the question: use "edit" to add the info there. Comments here are mainly just aimed at improving questions and answers.